# How does the vote counter work?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I accidentally downvoted an answer recently, and only realized from the rep tab, and had to do a silly edit to correct it.

Then I looked at my vote counter:

[image]

Then the downvote list, the actual downvotes are ***way*** less than what the counter shows.

I Googled the main meta site but I couldn't find a reason.

Do deleted posts retain the downvote after the review is completed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though the totals in the vote counter include deleted posts, the votes tab in the profile will not show them to you.

The values are all correct.